# InteliJ 2018.1.2 - Can not find main for Scala

Tags: scala, ide

For some reason my new InteliJ can not recognize Scala files and Main method for old project.

New Scala file - it can find Main and can Run.

But not old.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I faced a similar issue sometime back. I re-configured the Scala SDK after importing the older project in a new workspace. Went to project settings and configured it in Modules and Global Libraries.

Comment: You didn’t setup the sdk for the new project or try invalidate cache and restart. Then build the project

Comment: Thank  you........